# Alternate definition of the integers

Tags: integers, axioms, peano-axioms

Assuming we have already defined the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and function iteration $f^n$ for a natural number $n$, a set $A$ and a function $f:A\rightarrow A$, do the following axioms (based off the Peano axioms) define the set of integers?

1. There exist an element $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$
2. There exists a function $S:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$.
3. There exists a function $P:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ such that for every element $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $P(S(x)) = S(P(x)) = x$.
4. For all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ where $n\neq 0$ and for every element $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $S^n(x) \neq x$ and $P^n(x) \neq x$.
5. If $A$ is a set such that $0$ is in $A$ and, for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $S^n(0)$ being in $A$ implies that $S(S^n(0))$ is in $A$ and $P^n(0)$ being in $A$ implies that $P(P^n(0))$ is in $A$, then $A$ contains every integer.

Comment: I think you want $\quad ... S^{n+1}(0)$ is in $A ... P^{n+1}(0)$ is in $A ... $

Comment: Also, you will have to define addition and multiplication for this to work.

Comment: Addition hasn't been defined yet, though. The $S$ in the exponent refers to the successor function in the natural numbers. Perhaps I could just use $S(S^n(x)$ and $P(P^n(x))$ instead.

Comment: Why do you need to define addition and multiplication for this to work? Especially multiplication - the original definition of the integers by the Grothendieck construction does not need multiplication to be defined.

Comment: Sure, just addition is fine...

Comment: But function iteration is still just a way of extending the natural number ; you want the inverse of the $S$ to push to left - corresponding to the negative numbers. (+1) for ruminating on this...

Comment: @CopyPasteIt defining the negation unary function $-:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ as $-0 = 0$, $S(-x) = -P(x)$, and $P(-x) = -S(x)$ should work as well.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt I don't think the negation function (or addition) is necessary though. Axiom three establishes that $S$ and $P$ are inverse functions of each other. Axiom four establishes that neither $S$ nor $P$ are involutions. If $P(0) = S(0)$, then by axiom three $S(S(0)) = 0$, which violates axiom four. Thus, $P(0) \neq S(0)$, and if $S$ pushes to the right from 0, $P$ necessarily pushes to the left. The statement above still remains true for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @1103_base_6 function iteration is just another notation for addition ($S^x(y) = x + y = y + x = S^y(x)$) if $x$ and $y$ are both natural numbers or integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these questions you want to make sure that you are constructing a unique object identical to the integers and not a class of objects.

The parallels to the Peano axioms are clear:

- Axiom 1 is the same as the equivalent for the natural numbers, and
  rules out the empty set as a trivial object to the set of axioms.
- Axiom 2 is the same as the equivalent for the natural numbers, and
  asserts that the function $S$ is closed over the set.
- Axiom 3 corresponds to its equivalent for the natural numbers, and
  asserts that the function $S$ is bijective and has a unique inverse
  function $P$, (while the original for the natural numbers only
  asserts that the function $S$ is injective). It follows that the
  function $P$ is also closed over the set.
- Axiom 4 asserts that while $S$ is a permutation, the cardinality of the set is not finite. This disallows finite cycles from being defined.
- Axiom 5 is mathematical induction over the natural numbers on $S$ and
  $P$ and corresponds to its equivalent over $S$ for the natural
  numbers, and rules out any other elements other than those elements
  accessible from $0$ through function composition of $S$ and $P$, just
  as the original did for the natural numbers. Or equivalently, there does not exist a partition of the set into multiple mutually disjoint sets. This axiom also establishes that the set is countably infinite.
- For $n = 2$, axiom 4 asserts that neither $S$ nor $P$ are
  involutions, and with axiom 3, it follows that for every element $x$
  in the set, $S(x) \neq P(x)$, and the two functions $S$ and $P$ are
  not the same function. Therefore, the set is not identical to the
  natural numbers.

These axioms together construct a structure with an initial element $0$ and two countably infinite arms branching off from $0$ in distinct directions, defined by function iteration of $S$ and $P$; this uniquely forms the integers.

One can check indeed that this is isomorphic to the usual construction of the integers by equivalence classes of natural numbers (which does not need addition either if function iteration is defined):

We define the equivalence class $[a, b] \equiv [c, d]$ if $S^a(d) = S^c(b)$. We define $0 = [k, k]$ for all natural numbers $k$, which satisfies axiom 1. For the integer $x = [a, b]$ for natural numbers $a$ and $b$, we define $S(x) = [S(a), b]$ and $P(x) = [a, S(b)]$. Axiom two is satisfied because the successor function $S$ is closed over the natural numbers. Axiom three is satisfied because $P(S(x)) = S(P(x)) = [S(a), S(b)] \equiv x$. Axiom four is satisfied because the natural numbers are not a cycle. And axiom five is satisfied because the construction does not construct any elements inaccessible from $0$.

Comment: One can define similar axioms by using negation in place of the predecessor, where negation is defined as $-:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, $-0 = 0$ and $S(-S(x)) = -x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.